# How to do if statement with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to do an `if` statement in jQuery, but it doesn't really work.

```
$("#button2").hide()
var score = 0;

//some code with button that is adding the score with score++ (working)

if(score >= 100) {
    $("#button2").show()
}
```

The if statement is not properly working.

```
        $("#grandmabutton1").hide()
        $("#farmbutton1").hide()
        $("#minebutton1").hide()
        $("#factorybutton1").hide()  

        $(function(){ 
            var score = 0;

            $("#p1").html("Your score is: " + score)

            $("#headbutton1").mousedown(function(){
                score++

                $("#p1").html("Your score is: " + score)
            })

            if(score >= 100) {
                $("#grandmabutton1").show()
            }


        })
```

Comment: What do you mean the if statement is not properly working? What is it supposed to do? Make sure to perform the check every time you increment the `score`. You can do that by putting it in a function and calling that right after you increment `score`.

Comment: Put the `if` inside of the event-handler for the score's increment, otherwise it's executed once (while the score is `0` according to your code) and then never revisited. And, assuming that's the case, the `if` statement is working perfectly; it's your expectations that are wrong.

Comment: If the score is bigger or equals 100 it will show second button @nbokmans

Comment: Put debugger in JavaScript and see what is the value of score

Comment: i added the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the if statement only checks once, before the button has been clicked. Because the score starts at 0, nothing happens. Javascript has no way of knowing that you want the if statement to run all the time unless you tell it when to run it.

To solve this, you can put the if statement in the click function of the button so that it will check every time.

```
$("#headbutton1").mousedown(function () {
    score++
    if (score >= 100) { // Every time you click the button, it should check if your score is more than 100
        $("#grandmabutton1").show()
    }
    $("#p1").html("Your score is: " + score)
})
```

This way, every time you click the button it will check if it's score is >= 100

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
$("#headbutton1").mousedown(function(){
    score++
    if(score >= 100) {
        $("#grandmabutton1").show()
    }
    $("#p1").html("Your score is: " + score)
})
```

What you want to do here is to evaluate the condition for each mousedown event. By including the if clause inside the function, you will be checking if the score is greater or equal than 100 each time the event is triggered, however, by putting it outside, it will be only executed once in runtime.

Also, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```
if (condition)
   statement1
[else
   statement2]
```

If statements are a part of JavaScript built in syntax, not modified in any way by jQuery, fyi. What jQuery does is to extend JS functionality, but it does not change the syntax of the language. So there are no jQuery if clauses, there are JS if clauses, and yours is properly formatted.

To avoid these kind of beginner confusions, I recommend you to use a code editor that proof-checks your code to see if there are syntax errors, so when you debug you know that the problem is in the workflow design and not in the syntax.